# Stargazer: Omit variables and replace with yes/no

Tags: r, regression, summary, stargazer

How can I omit several groups of covariates from the regression table and replace them with the group labels in stargazer?  For example, if under `city controls` there is `size` and `population`, and under `individual controls` there is `age` and `gender`, how can I omit `size`, `population`, `age`, and `gender` and instead have something like `city controls in the model?: no yes` and `individual controls in the model?: no yes`.

By the way, all covariates from the same group would join or leave the model together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a minimal example. Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
data("Produc", package="plm")

Produc$cat <- cut(Produc$gsp,
              breaks=quantile(Produc$gsp),
              labels=c('Bad', 'OK', 'Good', 'Great'))

fe <- plm(pcap ~ hwy + water + unemp + cat,
    data=Produc, index=c("state", "year"), model = "within")

stargazer(fe, type="text")

========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                        pcap            
----------------------------------------
hwy                   2.025***          
                       (0.054)          
                                        
water                 1.976***          
                       (0.043)          
                                        
unemp                  -17.644          
                      (19.716)          
                                        
catOK                 462.982*          
                      (269.838)         
                                        
catGood               679.697**         
                      (329.131)         
                                        
catGreat               430.046          
                      (388.285)         
                                        
----------------------------------------
Observations             815            
R2                      0.902           
Adjusted R2             0.895           
F Statistic  1,170.861*** (df = 6; 761) 
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Use the option `omit` to omit certain variables. And option `add.lines` to add any note you like.

```
stargazer(fe, type="text", omit = "cat")
stargazer(fe, type="text", omit = "cat", 
          add.lines=list(c("Cats", "YES")))

========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                        pcap            
----------------------------------------
hwy                   2.025***          
                       (0.054)          
                                        
water                 1.976***          
                       (0.043)          
                                        
unemp                  -17.644          
                      (19.716)          
                                        
----------------------------------------
Cats                     YES            
Observations             815            
R2                      0.902           
Adjusted R2             0.895           
F Statistic  1,170.861*** (df = 6; 761) 
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```